# Widget not appearing or loading on a specific Iphone

Tags: ios, xcode, widget

I made a widget based off of the default template. It works on my phone when I run it on that, but when I uploaded it to TestFlight, one of my testers did not get the widget (he has an Iphone 6s). I checked with other testers and it showed up for them, so I tried installing the widget by running it from xcode and it still did not work. It doesn't crash, the app starts up fine except for the fact that it doesn't do anything. `viewDidLoad()` doesn't get called, along with `widgetPerformUpdate()`.

The app runs fine on his phone, and other testers with a 6s didn't have any issue with using the widget.

Is there anything I can do or is it safe to assume it is a bug on the specific device? How can I troubleshoot this if no functions are getting called?

The only other thing I noticed about the phone is that the charging port was damaged in some way, making somewhat difficult to run the widget without the device being disconnected from xcode. However I am fairly certain I was able to completely run the widget with breakpoints and none of them were triggered.